# Why aren't macroscopic objects—or really the entire universe—coherent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence, coherence

From what I understand, when quantum particles interact with the environment, they get entangled with it and the entanglement rapidly spreads until it's dispersed into the environment. So wouldn't this mean that a particle that has undergone decoherence is actually just entangled with the environment so you can't really observe its "quantumness" within the environment? And since entanglement "spreads" the coherence (if I understand correctly), wouldn't this mean that the entire environment is technically coherent but we just can't observe it? How do things become decoherent (i.e. how do the wave functions become no longer aligned with each other)?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have a look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence  . This paragraph is a clear way, in my opinion, to understand  decoherence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence#Density-matrix_approach

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and AFAIC is enough to show that there is a fundamental problem with the idea of a universal wave function. If we exclude classicality from the start, there is no way to get classicality back at any point.

Comment: @annav I see. Though how would that correspond to what happens to the wave functions? I don't exactly understand what the environment does that causes the wave function to collapse. How is it any different from any other random particle getting entangled with the quantum particle?

Comment: collapse is shorthand for interaction, the wavefunction changes every time there is an interaction and in the macroscopic case of $10^{24}$ molecules for mole of large masses there are innumerable interactions.

Comment: @annav Oh I see. So does that mean every interaction/entanglement "decays" the wave function until it eventually collapses? And would it mean that nothing is really entangled with the environment (since the wave function would have collapsed)?

Comment: It is more complicated, if one had infinite measuring accuracy, a time dependent wave function of the whole universe would exist , in the density matrix formalism with a huge number of dimensions and non zero submatrices. BUT our measurement accuracy is limited , and  within this accuracy the submatrices are equivalent to zero, and only the diagonal exists.

Comment: @annav Oh okay, I'm not too familiar with the math behind quantum mechanics. I'm mostly looking for the intuition behind decoherence. So do interactions somehow affect the wave function in a way that causes decoherence? And would the universe exhibit quantum behavior to an extent? (The two ideas—that the wave functions of objects are decoherent but the universe is coherent seem contradictory to me.) Sorry for all of the questions! If you could point me to a resource I would really appreciate that!

Comment: the  only resource is a course learning the mathematics of quantum mechanics, imo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment thread looks a bit like it's going in circles so I will just make the bold claim. To the best of our knowledge, macroscopic objects, including the entire universe, **are coherent**. The reason is exactly the one you mention. Statements about a system decohering after a certain time only make sense in a context where you specify what "the environment" is from the outset. If you could keep track of everything, e.g. a joint wavefunction of $10^{24}$ particles, then the Schroedinger equation would show that entanglement just builds up forever.

From the birth of "modern physics", there have been heated arguments about the idea that a quantum system never becomes classical. But 100 years later, there is still no direct evidence that unitary evolution is an approximation or that more than one wavefunction exists at a fundamental level. Quantum mechanics does not contain the seeds of its own destruction.

What I've just described is usually called the *many worlds interpretation* to reflect the wavefunction of the universe being something other than a delta function which has "collapsed" to just one possibility. However, the word "interpretation" above is a bit misleading. The theory that everyone uses to explain experiments has the lack of wavefunction collapse as an *unambiguous prediction*. Attempts to have collapse be something fundamental rather than an approximation / teaching tool are governed not by data or internal consistency but simply by taste. People who are uncomfortable with the fact that QM has to be made more complicated before it will no longer imply many worlds accept this tradeoff and make QM more complicated.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense! I just have one quick (I promise) question: I've heard a lot of sources say that macroscopic objects *aren't* coherent—is this just relative to the environment (because you realistically can't measure it's wave function once the entanglement disperses into the environment) or simply a different interpretation? Thank you so much!!

Comment: They almost certainly mean this in the practical sense. Due to dispersing entanglement, any imperfect observer will see something that looks like collapse whether or not there has really been one.

Comment: Got it, thank you again!